# TFS and VS2015: how to diff large amount of changed files?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, refactoring, diff

I'm currently refactoring a large set of files. I currently have 450 files in my pending changes list. The refactoring has been done mostly in automated fashion using ReSharper.

I want to preview these changes before I check them in. I am currently selecting each file and clicking "Compare with Latest Version" on each of them. This is slow and takes a lot of effort.

Is there any way to create a github-style diff (with VS2015/TFS) that lists all the files and all the diffs in a single listing? Such as for example this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/828a2757b2e04a3bec12012c127812559fab78e3

If not, are there any other ways that could be used for previewing the diffs faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further googling I found **Diff All Files for VS2015** add-on which does exactly what I wanted. It allows to combine all file changes into a single united diff.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deadlydog.DiffAllFilesforVS2015